# Asus Motherboard don't have Raid settings

Tags: raid, raid-0, asus

i have asus h310 prime plus
in detail in asus site this have Intel® H310
https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/PRIME/PRIME-H310-PLUS/techspec/

and intel h310 support rapid storage and raid
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/133348/intel-h310-chipset/specifications.html

but in my bios nothing is for raid and rapid storage ...
why ??

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: RAID is not mentioned at all in your h310 links. Why do you think it's supported?

Comment: @harrymc do "Intel Rapid Storage" means support raid ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Rapid_Storage_Technology

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005789/technologies.html + 
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005803/technologies.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not see the RAID option in the BIOS, then it is not supported
in your hardware configuration.

Some references below:

[**Motherboard specification ASUS PRIME H310-PLUS**](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/h310m-pro-m2-plus-raid-issues.331419/)

[image]

[**H310M PRO-M2 Plus RAID Issues**](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/h310m-pro-m2-plus-raid-issues.331419/)

> RAID is not supported by H310 chipset, neither optane memory